# Havok SDK and Android, where to begin

Tags: android, havok

The Havok games SDK is cross platform and supports android according to this link http://www.havok.com/solutions/mobile-game-developers

I want to explore the sdk but don't know from where to begin, didn't find any resources on how to use Havok with Android.

can anybody provide me with links,books, resources on how to start.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I downloaded the free binaries from here software.intel.com/sites/havok/en and found support forum from here software.intel.com/en-us/forums/havok

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you must buy Havok to get it for Android: http://www.havok.com/sales

Comment: ok, after buying it, how can I use it with my Android project; through the NDK or another tool ?

Comment: The product comes together with support from Havok developers. They will be able to answer your questions.